# Adding an apostrophe before a certain number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add an apostrophe to the front of numbers in a column only if the number in the column begins with a "0." There are a mix of many different numbers in the column, however for numbers which do not start in zero, I do not want an apostrophe added.

```
Sub RANGE
    For Each Cell in Range ("E:E")

    If cell.value= starts with a 0 then Cell.value = " ' "

Sub Addapostrophe()
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that?  It is merely a display feature which will not show up in the cell, and you can accomplish the same display by either leaving that column formatted as text, or by using a custom format.

Comment: Also, the whole `Sub Range` bit won't and shouldn't work. A) `Range` is a reserved word in VBA, B) Theres no `()` after it, C) There's no `End Sub`, D) There's no `Next Cell`, E) You're looping through an entire column, F) There's no `End Sub`...Is that to be psusedocode of the `Addapostrophe()` sub?

Comment: I agree with @RonRosenfeld tho.. "you can accomplish the same display by either leaving that column formatted as text, or by using a custom format"

Comment: Why not just use a formula, if absolutely necessary? `=IF(LEFT(E1,1)=0,"'"&E1,"")`?

Answer (score 0):

This will work...

```
Sub Addapostrophe()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("E:E")

    For Each cell In rng
        If Left(cell.Value, 1) = 0 Then
            cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is very basic for you basic question. You should ideal declare your variables, set your ranges etc.. One thing your code does is read EVERY cell in col 'E'.. that over 1M cells if your using the latest excel..